# Android Bluetooth Profile - AVRCP Version on JellyBean

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, bluetooth-audio

My Car audio system supports AVRCP v1.3 which, when my iPhone 4 buddies play music over BT, the song title is displayed on the radio... I have just upgraded to JellyBean and find that i am still not having any luck with my android device

Phone Specs

- Samsung Galaxy s i9000
- Android Version 4.1.1
- ROM MIUI-2.10.5 JellyHeff

Wikipedia quotes:
AVRCP has several versions with significantly increasing functionality:

- 1.0—Basic remote control commands (play/pause/stop, etc.)
- 1.3—all of 1.0 plus metadata and media-player state support The status of the music source (playing, stopped, etc.) Metadata
  information on the track itself (artist, track name, etc.).
- 1.4—all of 1.0, 1.3, plus media browsing capabilities for multiple media player Browsing and manipulation of multiple players Browsing
  of media metadata per media player, including a "Now Playing" list
  Basic search capabilities

Any Ideas where the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that base android supports avrcp beyond version 1.0.  A lot of the community created ROMs have added support for the other levels into their custom systems. However the stock version doesn't have it.

Comment: Thanks!... I have tried a few of the custom ROM's but still have not found one that supports later versions... I would love to hear from anyone that has got this working?

Comment: I have CM10 on my Galaxy Infuse. Google Play Music transmits song metadata but not Pandora sadly. My car stereo is a Pioneer AVH P2400BT.

Comment: See the CM10 changelog where they added AVRCP support, https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_vendor_cyanogen/blob/gingerbread/CHANGELOG.mkdn